# Zend Framework Autoloading in 3 modules

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to ZF and I am writing in Zend Framework 1.10 .
Here is my application directory structure.

```
APPLICATION_PATH`
├─configs
 ├─layouts
 └─modules
    ├─admin
    │  ├─controllers
    │  ├─forms
    │  ├─models
    │  └─views
    │      ├─filters
    │      ├─helpers
    │      └─scripts
    │          ├─authentication
    │          ├─cars
    │          └─index
    └─default
        ├─controllers
        ├─forms
        │  └─admin
        ├─models
        │  └─DbTable
        ├─plugins
        └─views
            ├─helpers
            └─scripts
                ├─about
                ├─contact
                ├─error
                ├─index
                ├─insurance
                └─used-cars
```

I have 3 bootstrap.php files in APPLICATION_PATH, /default/ and /admin,

i used AutoLoader to load models and forms

```
// APPLICATION_PATH/Bootstrap.php
$modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
'namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'));
```

The code above will load all models and forms automatically in modules/default, and now, I have a problem to call forms and models in /modules/admin/models and /modules/admin/forms in default module.

Any solutions to solve this problem? 
How should I name the class name in /modules/admin

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each of your modules should have a module bootstrap.

```
<?php
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

the module bootstrap sets up default autoloaders for that module.

## UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

make sure your ini is set up to Bootstrap modules

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Then make sure each of your modules has a bootstrap class (see above).

Comment: I've done this and used them but all bootstraps get fired when the application loads?

Comment: I added another chunk of code to my answer giving additional info on how to prepare your modules for bootstrap. To answer your question: Yes all of the bootstraps should get fired IF you have your modules set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Zend Tool](http://www.slideshare.net/ZendCon/zendtool-practical-use-and-extending) - it will create all necessary paths and files for you and is a good way to get started with Zend.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is add another module autoloader to load the Admin module:

```
$adminLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
    'namespace' => 'Admin', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin'));
```

add it after the original module auotloader. You can then reference things in the Default module by just creating them.

```
$form = new Admin_Form_TheForm();
```

Comment: Better to let ZF do this for you in the module bootstrap as per Francis' answer.